# Do world events/loot determine the probability of other world events?

Tags: sea-of-thieves

My friends and I have begun to run Athena Emissary quests, as it's our next guild to level up. We grabbed a Voyage that basically lead us back and forth between 2 islands for all 5 quests. Once we had completed our Athena quest, we had a huge chunk of Athena loot and other items, but we were still only Emissary Rank 4, and there are a number of commendations for selling Athena treasures at Rank 5.

To increase our rank to 5, we decided to sail off to Flameheart to complete his battle. On the way to Flameheart, we had two different Skeleton Galleons spawn at different times. We killed them off, and got even more loot onto our boat. We reach Flameheart and complete the event; huzzah, Emissary Rank 5! While collecting loot from the final battle, a Kraken spawns and wraps itself around our ship. Low on cannonballs from the Flameheart event, this was tough, but we had plenty of wood to repair and last it out until the Kraken gives up. A few minutes later, a Megalodon shows up, and begins chewing holes in our ship. This was too much for the four of us to repair, and our ship sunk. Thankfully we had stored everything in our rowboat, which barely survived.

My question is, **does the probability of PvE world events increase as you complete other events and quests, and potentially increase depending on how much loot you have on your ship?** This was a ridiculous amount of PvE stuff to happen all at once, but maybe we just got unlucky?

Answer (score 1):

On its own the act of doing a fort or Flameheart does not increase it.  Something that some people don't know is most world events (any except Fort of the Damned since it is player activated) block Kraken spawns.  So if you see a Skull fort, ashen winds, ship cloud, or Flameheart in the sky the kraken can't spawn.  So if you just finished one, looted the island quickly and leave before a new world event appears in the sky it is likely that you or another ship on the server will get the Kraken.  This is only for the Kraken though, the Megs and ships can spawn whenever.

Comment: The second paragraph is the real answer here.  This anecdotal event is simply a world event that the players chose to participate in, followed by the next spawned world event, followed by a random chance encounter (which happens probably at least once per hour).  The amount of loot had no influence on this; it was just an unfortunate coincidence.

Comment: You are correct I looked further into this and it is entirely coincidental and not causal so I removed that part to avoid confusion.